# Working with java media framework in Android

Tags: java, android, jmf

Is it possible to use JMF in Android? JMF has good functionality?
I'm basically trying to create a video in my android app. So any other ideas for creating the video are welcome. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JMF` will not work in `Android.`use `MediaPlayer API` instead.

[Media and Camera](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html)

Comment: Uh, do you know if it's possible creating a video file in the MediaPlayer API?

Comment: I see, do you aware of any other library for creating a video?

Comment: @idish, there is a framework called Xuggler in Java,do not know for Android.http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler

Answer (score 0):

Xuggler doesn't work on android...
You should compile and use FFMEP, like in this tutorial :
[FFMEP tutorial](http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/)